# Use downloaded picture for login image

Tags: macos, login, system-settings

For macOS Sierra I am trying to change the login image. I am going to System Preferences → Users & Groups and clicking on the edit button on the image.

An image selection popup appears. I have to add an image to any of the location so that I can select that images (I downloaded from internet) but none of the location is accessible.

There are locations like "Photo Booth" "iPhoto" "Photos" etc but I couldn't find the location where I can copy my newly downloaded picture.

Comment: Related (for a different version of Mac): [How do I set a custom avatar for my account profile in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/62836/55584)

Answer (score 4):

Within the **Users & Groups** panel, click and drag the image onto the profile picture circle.

[image]